# windows IntelliJ maven dependences error

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

Why IntelliJ cannot find these dependences?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you considered accpeting my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the mentioned classes come from Apache Spark SQL which is missing on your classpath. Add this:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```